# Can I get logcat logs after phone reboots?

Tags: android, reboot, logcat

I'm testing an android application with a long running service. I'm using Eclipse and have the usb cord hooked up with the phone sitting next to me. Since it's a long ongoing service, I do some other work while it runs and check the logcat logs every once in a while to make sure everything is going as expected.

A few minutes ago I noticed the phone rebooting. I think it's done this before as it would explain some weird application behavior. I quickly switched over to Eclipse to see what happened and found that the logcat log was (it seems) cleared during the reboot. So there's no log of whether my app crashed (and took down the phone?!) or if there was some other problem that took down the phone and my app.

Is there anyway I can find out what happened? This is a development phone, so I don't know if it reboots/crashes often on its own, or only while my app is running. It's a Motorola Droid running Firmware version 2.1-update1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361230/android-retrieve-logcat-before-crash-reboot-on-a-real-device

If you know how to open a console to your phone(sorry I dont) then this might help you out.  You can add the -f parameter and specify a file to have all the logs piped to so that you can go get it after the reboot.

Comment: May not be particular to your situation, but in case it helps somebody... I've found using up too many systems resources can cause spurious reboots which are difficult to track down via logs.  For instance, if you have something generating intents but you aren't listening to them (for instance, if your listening thread gets blocked.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to get kernel logs after kernel panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this. However, you could start up logcat in `adb` with `adb logcat -v time > logcat.txt` and then run your app again. If it crashes a second time, then you can go look at the output in `logcat.txt` on your machine.

Comment: Note that file writes are buffered, so the very last words before rebooting may not be flushed to the file.

Comment: @adamk: Also a good point. Is there a cleaner way to do this (I'm guessing `adb bugreport`)?

Comment: @eldarerathis: you guessed right :) - I used it a couple of times, and it proved useful. BTW - running `adb shell logcat -f file.txt` may be better (in the buffering sense) than just piping using the shell, but it's really just a guess.

Comment: I was able to catch a crash, and this line from the log: `08-12 11:22:50.568 E/mdm_panicd( 1002): Modem has reset, reboot system!` Thanks! This has helped.

Comment: @adamk: I'll have to test that sometime. I've got Unix `bash` syntax so stuck in my head that I just automatically use `>` without even thinking about it. Not to say that I don't love `bash`, of course.

Comment: `adb shell logcat -f file.txt` lead to `couldn't open output file: Read-only file system` ;( It's my private phone. Dont want to route it.

Comment: @OneWorld: Try taking `shell` out of the command. `adb shell logcat` will try to run logcat on the phone and save the output file to the phone's filesystem. Executing it without shell should cause logcat to run on your computer instead. If you want to save the log to your phone then you could try an absolute path to a writable directory - maybe `adb shell logcat -f /sdcard/file.txt` or something.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just used this with great success to work out why the emulator, when running 4.4.2, was rebooting every time I tried to run my application. It captured a SIGABRT event to do with `SensorService`. After I disabled the use of internal sensors in my application, it is now running on the emulator just fine.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `adb bugreport`, which should contain some information regarding a spurious reboot - for example, a kernel panic, last logcat entries etc.

Be warned, though: this tool outputs immense amounts of information, so you'll have to dig deep to find what you need.

Comment: Wow. That gave me 20,000+ lines. I'm sure it's great information, though I don't know what to do with it!

Comment: @Scott: I'd start by searching inside your app's package id, log tags etc. to see if there's anything related to your app.

Comment: I'm looking through it now. I'm not seeing anything from before the reboot, though. Maybe I waited too long? It's been about two hours since the last reboot.

Answer (score 1):

On newer android versions you can try the following command

```
adb logcat -b all -L
```

This should output the contents of '/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0'.

Note: This command does NOT work if your OS still uses /proc/last_kmsg for its last reboot logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem as well.  It should be possible to write an app that continuously saves the logcat output to a file on the SD card.  There are apps on the market that display the logcat output, so I know it is accessible from within an application.

@djv, I wasn't able to find a /log directory in either root or /data on my phone.

Comment: Logs aren't flushed to the disk in Android... they are stored as circular memory buffers. So they won't persist after your phone reboots.

Comment: @AlexLockwood that's not quite correct (anymore). have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525021/529977 `/data/dontpanic`

Comment: My comment was based on information I read in this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do If logs were constantly written to disk devices would perform very poorly. So I stand by my comment. Also this answer is definitely not true anymore since apps are no longer able to access logcat since API 16.

Answer (score 0):

I think that during one of major android update, crash logs are moved from `/proc/last_kmsg` to `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0`