# Testing an android app for restart functionality

Tags: android, logcat, reboot

I am trying to develop an Android App that, though having an Activity, needs to run in the background as a service. The app needs to start up automatically after rebooting the phone/device.

My question is HOW to troubleshoot such requirements, since the LogCat gets disconnected when the phone is rebooted, even using "adb shell broadcast -am  android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" on a connected phone. (Though possible on an emulator, I dont feel like it is able to properly replicate real-world scenarios). I would like to be able to see the Logcat messages after device restarts, thus allowing me to troubleshoot ANRs and app crashes during reboot.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: did you set the permission in manifest.xml ?

Comment: yes... permissions were set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469016/can-i-get-logcat-logs-after-phone-reboots), I understand the closest we can get to debugging reboot errors is to use

```
adb logcat -v time > <localfile>
```

or

```
adb bugreport
```

Both of these options may not be the cleanest ways to pinpoint the issue, but atleast something is better than nothing.