# Debugging a rebooted device

Tags: android, android-2.0-eclair

I have an application which shows some weird behaviour on one of my testing-devices (X10 Mini Pro, Android 2.1-update1). Basically it's a clock radio that uses shoutcast for radio.

**The problem:**
When the phone has been idle for a long time (night) and the alarm should go off (morning) it reboots. After that I can't get a logcat of what happened so I don't know how to find out what's causing this (logcat is cleared on boot).

I've tried `adb bugreport` but it also gives only values from *after* the boot.

Comment: from where you see logcat from adb or in ddms with eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Can you have your own logging mechanism?
I mean, have a file on the SD Card that your application keeps writing into.
I am not sure about the level of the details in the log, but you can save your own messages into it.

I am wondering why the phone reboots.
On the other note, if its a testing device, can you leave it untouched for the whole day and set an alarm for the evening to see what's happening? (This might not be a good solution, but can be tried if nothing works)

Comment: Yea think I should try the logging-to-SD. Have read that it is delayed a little, though, so I hope it's fast enough to write before it boots.

Are there any apps that will do this or do I have to write my own? :P

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361230/android-retrieve-logcat-before-crash-reboot-on-a-real-device